# WP_Queryを使ってタグによる検索を行い、一致したタグの個数が多い順に並び替えたい

Tags: wordpress

現在表示中の記事と関連する記事を表示させたいと思っています。
記事には複数のタグがつけられており、タグの一致している数の多い順に並び替えて表示したいのですが、うまい方法が分かりません。

例えば以下の様な記事が投稿されているとします。（あ〜おは投稿記事のタイトル、カッコ内の数字はタグのIDを表しています）

投稿日時古い
あ（1,2）
い（1,2,3）
う（）
え（2,3）
お（1）
投稿日時新しい

投稿「あ」を表示しているときに、以下のクエリを発行して実行します。

```
$args = array(
    'post__not_in'=>$post->ID,
    'tag__in' => array(1,2),
);
$related_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if($related_posts->have_posts()){
    while($related_posts->have_posts()){
        $related_posts->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

すると以下のように表示されます。

```
お
え
い
```

今回の質問は、投稿「い」が一番上に表示されるようにするにはどうしたらよいか、というものです。

'tag__in'の代わりに'tag__and'を使ってクエリを発行してみたのですが、'tag__and'では投稿「い」を表示していると、関連記事が1つも表示されなくなってしまいます。（1,2,3のタグすべてを持つ記事が他にないため）
「い」を表示しているときには、「あ、え、お」という順番で表示されるようにしたいのです。（タグの一致個数が同じものの順番にはこだわりはありません）
何かよい方法はないものでしょうか？

Comment: [wp query - Order posts by tags count?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173949/order-posts-by-tags-count)

Comment: 教えていただいた情報を元にSQL文を加工することで実現することができました。ありがとうございます。